# xml root element missing

Tags: c#, xml

Sorry for the simplicity, but this one is eluding me , hier is the xml soap request  :

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <TarifResponse xmlns="http://www.april-technologies.com">
      <TarifResult>
        <Status>
          <Summary>
            <ResponseTechnicalLabel />
            <ResponseTechnicalData>OK</ResponseTechnicalData>
          </Summary>
        </Status>
        <BusinessData>
          <IdentifiantProjet>1296483</IdentifiantProjet>
          <Proposition>
            <PropositionOutput>
              <Ordre>1</Ordre>
              <Produit>SanteEssentiel</Produit>
              <Garantie>
                <GarantieOutput>
                  <Libelle>Niveau 1</Libelle>
                  <CotisationMensuelle>5998</CotisationMensuelle>
                </GarantieOutput>
              </Garantie>
              <ValiditeTarif>
                <DateDebut>01/01/2014</DateDebut>
                <DateFin>31/12/2014</DateFin>
              </ValiditeTarif>
              <OptionProduit />
            </PropositionOutput>

          </Proposition>
        </BusinessData>
      </TarifResult>
    </TarifResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the code c# is

```
XDocument docxx = XDocument.Parse(Session["xmlrs" + z + ""].ToString());
            //This now holds the set of all elements named field

            try
            {
                XNamespace foobar = "http://www.april-technologies.com";
                var urlList = docxx.Descendants(foobar + "CotisationMensuelle")
                                      .Select(x => (string)x)
                                      .ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(urlList);




                rpMyRepeater1.DataSource = urlList;
                rpMyRepeater1.DataBind();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
```

??? hou i can get the data "CotisationMensuelle" ??? i get null data , hou ik can fix this problem ?

Comment: "CotisationMensuelle" is inside GarantieOutput... So something like: Root -> TarifResult -> BusinessData -> Proposition -> Garantie -> GarantieOutput -> CotisationMensualle

Comment: You can use XPath 2: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/ ...and write something like: XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); Load... xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode ("//CotisationMensuelle").Value; or something like this =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method as below

```
XNamespace foobar = "http://www.april-technologies.com";
var urlList = docxx.Descendants(foobar + "CotisationMensuelle")
                      .Select(x => (string)x)
                      .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(urlList.Count);
```

if you try to use `Element` or `Elements` you have to go full hierarchy

```
XNamespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace ns1 = "http://www.april-technologies.com";

var CotisationMensuelle=(string)xml.Root
                      .Element(soapenv + "Body")
                      .Element(ns1 + "TarifResponse")
                      .Element(ns1 + "TarifResult")
                      .Element(ns1 + "BusinessData")
                      .Element(ns1 + "Proposition")
                      .Element(ns1 + "PropositionOutput")
                      .Element(ns1 + "Garantie")
                      .Element(ns1 + "GarantieOutput")
                      .Element(ns1 + "CotisationMensuelle");
```

Comment: i have tested u 1st code Thanks it worked , but i have  this message "[System.InvalidCastException] = {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Xml.XmlNode'."}" when i put the data in `rpMyRepeater1.DataSource = urlList; 
                rpMyRepeater1.DataBind();`???? what wrong in my code ?

Comment: change `Label1.Text=urlList.ToString()` to `Label1.Text=urlList.First()`

Comment: the full message is` System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char' to type 'System.Xml.XmlNode'.
   
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()
   at aprilService.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)  c:\WebSite1\WebSite1\aprilService.aspx.cs:line 122 'rpMyRepeater1.DataBind();'`

Comment: this is Repeater binding issue , you better ask new question  with repeater binding related code